# Cannot install Pex (Win XP - SP2, VS2010 Beta 2)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pex

When trying to install PEX, its been stuck at the "Please wait while installer determines disk space requirements" dialogue for over  7hours. I'm installing this on a virtual machine (virtual pc 2007 x64)

As I have mentioned in the Title, the VPC is running XP Service Pack 2 and I have installed VS2010 Beta 2. Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like a better question for superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I installed some recommended hotfixes from Windows Update, Pex installed just fine.

Answer (score -1):

from the pex download page

***Requirements***
Windows Vista 32bit / 64bit 
**Other versions of Windows (XP, W2K3, W2K8) should work but are untested.** 
On x64, only 32-bit (Wow64) processes are supported.
.NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0

also, if you are using the commercial eval version:

***This version requires Visual Studio 2008/2010 Team Dev or Team Test.***